# foursquare api data pull from databricks

Tags: python, foursquare, pyspark

I am using the following command to pull data from foursquare api which is working fine. How can I write the json output as table in databricks? I can't use show/display functions on data output.

```
import json, requests
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore'

params = dict(
  client_id='CLIENT_ID',
  client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET',
  v='20180323',
  ll='40.7243,-74.0018',
  query='coffee',
  limit=1
)
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = json.loads(resp.text)
```

Comment: You can dump the JSON responses into a file and then read it back into a DataFrame using Spark `spark.read.json`. Or you can create directly a DF from the JSON string as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676143/1386551).

Answer (score 0):

You could read and write the data received as follows:

```
df = spark.read.json(resp.text)
location = 'dbfs:/tmp/test.json'
df.write.json(location)
```

and then create a table using the file created :

```
spark.sql(f'''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foursquare
USING JSON 
LOCATION "{location}"
''')
```

Comment: I am getting this error df = spark.read.json(json.loads(resp.text))
 :- TypeError: path can be only string, list or RDD