# How to convert a JSON string to dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to convert a JSON string to dataframe. I am not able to do.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc=spark.sparkContext
some_json_string = """
[
  {"id":1, "name":"test1"},
  {"id":2, "name":"test2"}
  {"id":3, "name":"test3"}
]
"""

df = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json(sc.parallelize(some_json_string))

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I am getting the error

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+
|_corrupt_record|
+---------------+
|              [|
|              {|
|              "|
|              i|
|              d|
|              "|
|              :|
|              1|
|              ,|
|              "|
|              n|
|              a|
|              m|
|              e|
|              "|
|              :|
|              "|
|              t|
|              e|
|              s|
+---------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

How can I convert this into PySpark dataframe?

I also tried:

[image]

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. You are missing comma after the object for `id2`.

Comment: that was the issue, now it works

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675860/pyspark-converting-json-string-to-dataframe), you must pass the JSON string as a list like so:
`df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([newJson]))`

Your new code would be:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc=spark.sparkContext
some_json_string = """
[
  {"id":1, "name":"test1"},
  {"id":2, "name":"test2"}
  {"id":3, "name":"test3"}
]
"""

df = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json(sc.parallelize([some_json_string]))

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Comment: I have tried it still error

Comment: updated my question with what i get